# GROUP BY и его распорядок строк

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Смотрю в большинстве примеров почему-то результат запроса с ключевым словом GROUP BY выдает отсортированные данные. Я делаю тоже самые запросы в PostgreSQL только со своей таблицей, результат отображается правильно, но не в отсортированном виде. В чем проблема, в том что GROUP BY просто группирует и не должен сортировать или я неправильно написал?

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM shop GROUP BY id;

 id | count 
----+------- 
 11 |     1 
  9 |     1
 15 |     1
  3 |     1
  5 |     1
  4 |     1
 10 |     1
  6 |     1
 14 |     1
 13 |     1
  2 |     1
 16 |     1
  7 |     1
 12 |     1
  1 |     1
  8 |     1
```

Comment: *в большинстве примеров почему-то результат запроса с ключевым словом GROUP BY выдает отсортированные данные* Исключительно для MySQL, причём версии младше восьмой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROUP BY` только группирует.
Никакой гарантии на порядок - нету.
Если нужен порядок - всегда добавляйте `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! А то, где не прочтешь или не увидишь пример, везде отсортировано, возможно для наглядности сделано.

Comment: Вообще, обычно, результаты запросов возвращаются отсортированными по id, но полагаться на это не стоит.

Comment: `обычно, результаты запросов возвращаются отсортированными по id` - нет. По стандарту если не указана явная сортировка СУБД имеет право выдавать результат в любом удобном для себя порядке. Хоть каждый раз в разном порядке. Если запрос несколько раз подряд выдал результат в одном порядке - это значит только то, что так получилось случайно.

Comment: @Мелкий неточно выразился. О том и речь, что "обычно" результаты расположены по возрастанию id, но никаких гарантий на этот счет нет. И никакой специальной сортировки не выполняется, да.

Comment: Нет никакого "обычно". Особенно в (на данный момент) heap-only postgresql. Как базе удобно - так и вернёт результат. Если для вас обычно поиск по диапазону id - может быть будут в порядке id, потому что по первичному ключу искали indexscan'ом. Но если случайно переключится на bitmap scan - никакого порядка уже не будет. Ну разве только у вас append-only таблица. Это явно не может быть распространённым случаем.

Comment: @Мелкий "Обычно" вполне себе есть. Возьмите 1000 компаний, с 10000 БД, выполните на них 1000000 селектов - получите некое распределение порядков выдач.. Вы явно в теме подкапотных подробностей. Запостите свой ответ?

Comment: Значение будут иметь: какая структура таблиц, какие именно запросы, какие именно базы, как эти базы пишутся, особенно - update и delete, что именно пишется, что по этому поводу получилось в статистике планировщика и получился ли у него sample адекватный, какие `enable_*` отключены нерадивыми ручками. Да даже минорная версия базы может в граничных условиях вариации давать. Да, моё имя появится в release notes postgresql 12. Хоть в код планировщика я и не лезу - никакого "обычно упорядоченно по id" нет. Слишком много неизвестных и самое важное - каков план запроса. Обычного плана не существует.